# XAML Files .editorconfig rules

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

it is possible to declare a rule in .editorconfig for VS 2019 that xaml files must match Attribute Spacing and Element Spacing settings?
Thank you.
We need votes:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1078375/editorconfig-support-for-xaml-files.html

Comment: I also was looking to see how to have XAML formatting rules per project. Did you get any answer? Thanks

Comment: @DonBox No. It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be in the `.editorconfig`, but with the [XAML Styler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamXavalon.XAMLStyler) or [XAML Styler 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamXavalon.XAMLStyler2022) extension for Visual Studio you can define XAML styling in a [Settings.XamlStyler](https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/wiki/External-Configurations) file, just like you would do with a `.editorconfig` file.

If you need this outside of Visual Studio, then XAML Styler is available as a console app. So you can [integrate it](https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/wiki/Script-Integration) in you build scripts.

This is as close as we get to `.editorconfig`